# Do Tron video games include any canon expansion to the storyline

Tags: tron-legacy, tron

There are a few Tron Video games. Do they expand the story of Tron? If so, do those expansions considered canon?

Comment: I know there was at least one game (Tron 2.0? maybe?) that expanded the storyline, and *Legacy* took a different direction that negated the game's story.  Not familiar enough with the details to answer properly though.

Comment: This is just my opinion, but I tend to assume video games based on a movie (or a book) are not canon sources, unless the authors explicitly say they are.  Likewise, I don't consider movies based on a video game to be canon to the established video game storyline.  They have their own canon, but are effectively "alternate universes."

Comment: I agree that they are not canon unless stated as canon. That is why I am asking.  Are there any statements regarding canon games? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tron: Evolution is apparently canon for in between the first and second movies. Tron 2.0 (killer app) was questionably canonical until the second movie came out.

Teeeeechnically during the Tron ARG there was a version of Space Paranoids which we could play, which would technically make it a canon game even without any storyline.

None of the other Tron games have enough story to be canon.

Comment: When Tron 2.0 came out, somebody from the original film's creative staff said that the game was the official continuation of the story.  I can't recall who it was, though maybe I can find the interview again.  Obviously, this was subsequently retconned.

Comment: @Buzz right, that was my point, I just expressed it poorly. Thank you for clarifying and for the confirmation :)

Answer (score 1):

There were only 2 arcade games I've ever seen. 1, was the most fun-Discs of Tron. You were on a platform or 2 or 3. Your opponent on the other side. You'd throw discs back and forth off the walls, and use a shield to block un-dodgeable projectiles. The other, had a few different scenarios-piloting a light cycle being one of them. I failed to finish either game, but there is nothing mentioned on the arcade cabinets regarding any story. The games themselves are just games with the movie title thrown in to generate sales. Anything after 1990/95 would be new to me-such as Kingdom Hearts 2 or whatever anyone else is talking about. Those first 2 games did come out back in the 80s, and they were completely different.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/Canon) is an article on the TRON Wikia concerning what is and isn't canon. Apparently, the only canon game is *TRON: Evolution*. To sum it up, the following are canon:

- TRON
- TRON: Legacy
- TRON: Evolution *(Game)*
- TRON: Uprising

The following are not canon:

- TRON 2.0 *(Game)*
- TRON 2.0: Killer App *(Game)*
- TRON: The Ghost in the Machine
- TRON: Evolution - Battle Grids *(Game)*

> (Note the events in TRON: Betrayal and Evolution differ in how Clu
> took over the TRON system, with TRON: Evolution depicting the events
> to be very close to the film.
>
> According to Dave (a friend of Steven Lisberger, the creator and
> director of TRON), TRON is the only story that is truly
> canon.[citation needed] TRON 2.0's storylines differ from Lisberger's
> original intentions of the characters and the story, therefore, TRON
> 2.0 should be considered as its own canon. TRON: Legacy effectively ignores most of the material shown in TRON 2.0.

Comment: Does the wikia have any sources for how it deduces what is and isn't canon? It claims that "Dave" said something, but has no citation, this could just be made up, for all we know.

Comment: That article didn't list any citations unfortunately, but I think it's basing these claims on how the story in the games conflicts with the story in the movies or is confirmed by them. TRON 2.0 was released 7 years before TRON: Legacy, and the hostile merger of Encom with fCon and all that was never mentioned in Legacy. In Evolution, which was also released before Legacy, some events that happened in the game were mentioned in the movie (Flynn saving Quorra in the Outlands, etc). David Warner is the actor that played Sark and Ed Dillinger in TRON. I will see if I can dig up that quote...